# Why are the number of paths of length n-1 in $K_n$ the same as the number of labelled trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider the complete graph on $n$ vertices (where we allow self loops). It has adjacency matrix $J_{ij} = [1]$, the all 1s matrix. If we fix two vertices, the number of walks of length $n-1$ between them is the corresponding entry in $J^{n-1} = n^{n-2}J$ which is $n^{n-2}$.

This is also the number of labelled trees by [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula). Is there an explicit bijection between these two sets?

Comment: Shouldn't the adjacency matrix have zeros on the diagonal? With the way you are representing things, you are counting [self-loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)) as edges, so that your formula $J^{n-1} = n^{n-2} J$ does not really count paths of length $n-1$.

Comment: Do you want your graph to have self loops? If yes, then you should call it the "complete graph with self loops", as the complete graph typically doesn't have them. If no, then the adjacency matrix isn't the all 1s matrix - it is all 1s with 0s on the diagonal

Comment: Yea, I am allowing self loops so I guess I am really counting paths of length at most n-1 without loops?

Comment: The term "path" usually implies no vertex is revisited; I think people use the term ["walk"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_path) when you allow revisits (which your $J^{n-1}$ computation implies). So you are counting either a) the number of walks of length $=n-1$ in the complete graph with loops, or b) the number of walks of length $\le n-1$ in the complete graph [without loops]. I bring this up because all paths (no vertex repetition) in the complete graph [without loops] have length $\le n-1$ automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the terminology correction. I don't think i am counting walks of some max length without loops because there is a choice of where to put the loop.

Comment: you are right, I stand corrected

Comment: There is an obvious bijection between "paths in $K_n$ with self-loops of length $n-1$" and "lists of length $n-1$ with entries in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$." Then, there is a nice bijection between such lists and trees, using Prüfer sequences. See [this Wikipedia article describing how to convert a Prüfer sequence into a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence#Algorithm_to_convert_a_Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence_into_a_tree).